# Why the count is not printing after for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

After each loop `count` and `count1` are updated. After giving inputs in `Scanner`, I'm not getting any output.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = sc.nextInt(); // t=1
while (t != 0) {
    int n = sc.nextInt(); // n=5
    int a[] = new int[n]; // a = { 1,2,5,6,7 }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    int count = 0, count1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ((a[i + 1] - a[i]) > 2) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count1++;
        }
    }
    // this doesn't get printed
    System.out.println(count + 1 + " " + count1);

    t--;
}
```

Comment: You only assign a value to t once. If that value is not 0, the loop never ends.

Comment: Even after adding t--;  it shows the same thing

Comment: Are you sure your program hasn't died with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?  Because the `for` loop containing it runs until `i == n-1`, the statement `if ((a[i + 1] - a[i]) > 2)` (specifically, the `a[i+1]` bit) will blow up right when `i` does reach the value of `n-1` and the program will have never reached the `System.out.println` that follows the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions in the following code block will result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as when **i = n - 1**, `if ((a[i + 1] - a[i]) > 2)` will try to get an element from `a[n - 1 + 1]` i.e `a[n]` which you already know is invalid because the indices in `a[]` are in the range `0` to `n - 1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((a[i + 1] - a[i]) > 2)
```

You can put it like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n -1 ; i++) {
    if ((a[i + 1] - a[i]) > 2)
```

After this correction, given below is the result of a sample run:

```
1
5
1 2 5 6 7
2 3
```

It is because `count1++` gets executed for `1 2,`, `5 6` and `6 7` while `count++` gets executed only for `2 5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0,count1=0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

should be replaced with

```
int count=0,count1=0;
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
```

You are trying to access `n+1` memory location by `a[i + 1]` which is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.`

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to take continuously for test case input only `t--`  will not work here. I'm going to post here a generic structure for this. Try the following approach  -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
            int n = in.nextInt();
            //do your stuff here
            // now you could take input and process them t times
        }

        //finally don't forget to close the input stream.
        in.close();
    }
```